# What are the specific heats of Dysprosium in its gas phase?

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics, physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory

What are the specific heats of [Dysprosium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysprosium) in its gas phase?

The handbook of chemistry and physics [1], is a single volume of 1500 pages containing all the information an experimentalist would need about experimental constants. Despite this, I was unable to find the specific heat of Dysprosium in its gas phase. Listed only is its specific heat in the solid phase (at room temperature), on page 4-133.

I was wondering if anyone could provide me its specific heat? If not this, then the speed of sound within dysprosium gas.

Simple calculations can be made to figure out its specific heat, by treating it as an ideal monatomic gas (when a gas, it is indeed monatomic). For such cases specifics heats are given by the following

\begin{align}
C_{v,m}&=\frac{3}{2}R,\\
C_{p,m}&=\frac{5}{2}R,\\
\end{align}

where $C_{v,m}$ and  $C_{p,m}$ are the specific heats of the material per unit mass at constant volume and pressure respectively.

Such calculations are only approximations however, and are unlikely to model the behaviour well at all. What would be better is an experimentally measured value.

**Reference:**

[1] HAYNES, W. M. (2009). CRC handbook of chemistry and physics: a ready reference book of chemical and physical data. Boca Raton, CRC Press.

Comment: Well, clearly the CRC doesn’t have everything. The online NIST materials properties site may, or you will have to start digging into the literature. All depends on how exact you need things, but I’m assuming that you need more precision than treating it as an ideal gas.

Comment: 3/2 and 5/2 are an excellent approximation for *dilute monatomic* gases.  If that's what you are considering, don't feel guilty about using them.  Otherwise, the little corrections will be sensitive to temperature and pressure.

Comment: @BertBarrois Dysprosium gas is monatomic by definition, and the circumstances I am working in are such that it's dilute.  
The problem with this is the C_v and C_p I obtain using the approximations give it a speed of sound less than the rms velocity of the gas using the same formulation (assuming a dilute monatomic gas, which gives rise to a Maxwell Boltzmann distribution of speeds). The reason this occurs (I think) is because Dysprosium is so heavy it falls outside the range the approximations usually hold.

Comment: It is perfectly normal to have ${{v}_{rms}}>c$.  In three dimensions, $\tfrac{1}{2}\left\langle {{v}^{2}} \right\rangle =\tfrac{3}{2}RT/m$  and  ${{c}^{2}}=\tfrac{5}{3}RT/m$.